# Dispose_on_Close closes JFrame but it is still active

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I am writing a program where I need to open a JFrame if a button is clicked. I set the default close operation to Dispose_on_close so that when I close the window the program doesn't shutdown completely. 
In the frame that will be opened, i want to put a JTable, so I wrote two methods, a createFrame() method and a mechanicListTableProperties() which is the method that creates the JTable and adds elements to it. I then call the mechanicListTableProperties inside the createFrame() and the createFrame inside the actionPerformed() method. When I open the frame 1 time, the table is shown inside the window, but if I close and reopen the frame, the table is also readded and I see 2 tables, when I am trying to just see the one table again. Here is my source code:

```
public class SeeMechanicsButtonHandler implements ActionListener {      
    JFrame mechanicListFrame;
    boolean isOpen = false;     
    JTable mechanicListTable;   
    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout()); 
    JScrollPane sp;     
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();   
    String[] namesArray;

     public void createFrame() {        
        mechanicListFrame = new JFrame();
        mechanicListFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);       
        mechanicListFrame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));      
        mechanicListFrame.add(tablePanel);
        mechanicListFrame.setVisible(true);                 
        //Prevents the window from being opened multiple times  
        mechanicListFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){            
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {              
                isOpen = false;                 
            }       
        });          
    }

     public void mechanicListTableProperties(){
        mechanicListTable = new JTable(){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;           
            }       
        };      
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();  
        model.addColumn("Nome", namesArray); 
        //Creates a column with title as Nome and lines as the array    

        mechanicListTable.setModel(model); //adds column to the the table
        mechanicListTable.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300); //table size

        mechanicListTable.setFont(new Font("Arial Rounded MT", Font.BOLD, 15)); 
                        // adding it to JScrollPane
        sp = new JScrollPane(mechanicListTable);    
        tablePanel.add(sp);     
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    if(!isOpen) {       
        try {
             //SQL code to get the data from mechanics table
            ResultSet rs = ServerConnection.createQueryStatement("SELECT * FROM mechanics");
            while (rs.next()){
                //loop to add each entry in the table to an array list
                names.add(rs.getString("nome"));
                }
                //creates an array to put the values from the arraylist
                namesArray = new String[names.size()];
                for (int iterate = 0; iterate < names.size(); iterate++){
                    //loop that iterates through the arraylist and puts the values in the array
                    namesArray[iterate] = names.get(iterate);

                    System.out.println(namesArray[iterate]);
                     //prints to the console for testing purposes
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        createFrame();
        isOpen = true;
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` simply disposes of the connection to the OS, it does not dispose instance of the `JFrame`

Comment: Is there a way to dispose the instance?

Comment: Deference the variable (`mechanicListFrame = null`) when you're done with it

Comment: Is there a specific location in this code that i should put that in? I tried putting it inside the windowAdapter in the createFrame() method and  i tried in the if loop inside the actionPerformed() method, but I still keep getting a duplicate table when i press the button again

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing all the components inside the jframe, so that when it is called again, they are not already present and adding it "again" is the same as adding the first time. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it worked. Thank you for clearing up the referencing and dereferencing for me

Comment: A better solution is devising a method by which you create the frame and it's contents once and then simply update the data/models that it relies on

Comment: I will try to do that, as my solution really isn't ideal, but for that would I not need 2 actionPerformed methods? One for the first click of the button, that would create the table and put it in the frame, and the other for the following clicks, that would just update  the table. I found that the array too was duplicating, as in every click of the button it got the rows from the sql table. I added a clear so that when it read from the sql table, it wouldn't store a duplicate value